# Restricting tableau filter options without changing underlying data or display

Tags: tableau-api

I am looking for a way to restrict the filter options on a dashboard without changing the underlying data or display.

For example, with a dataset of 
Company A: 10 units.
Company B: 5 units.
Company C: 2 units.

I would like the Total Units to display as 17 when no filter is applied, however I would only like to show 'Company A' as an option in the filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see your data, so I'm approximating the column names and values. You'll have to adjust these on your end.

Create a parameter, like `CompanyFilterParameter`, with the values `'Company A'` and `'All'`.

Create a calculated field to use as your filter, `CompanyFilter`:

```
[CompanyFilterParameter] = [Company] OR [CompanyFilterParameter] = 'All'
```

Put `[CompanyFilter]` on the Filter card and set it to true. Finally, add your parameter control to the sheet (right click `[CompanyFilterParameter]` and select "Show Parameter Control").